# Run junk mail filter on inbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook, spam-prevention

I currently am running outlook office 365 ProPlus

I simply want to run the junk mail filter that comes with outlook against all the existing emails I have in my inbox. It only applies the rule on new emails received and not existing. I tried to create a rule to run the junk email filter bit there is nothing.. 
Also this is a pop3 account not an exchange server

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem- a bit clunky but it works.
In the junk email menu (under 'Delete', on the 'Home' tab), select the Blocked Senders icon, and choose 'Junk email options...' This brings up the Junk Email Options dialog box.
Choose the 'Blocked senders' tab, then use the 'Export to File' dialog to save a list of your blocked senders to a text file somewhere readily accessible.
Once you've got that text file, you can cut and paste the list to quickly generate a new Rule for your inbox. Then you can run that rule on your inbox as per the previous suggestion.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have ticked the option below.

[image]

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that. It works for rules but not the junk filter. The reason is the junk filter is not part of the rule function. It is a seperate feature. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Does the junk filter belong to Outlook built-in features?

Comment: Yes it has it own options and features seperate from the email rules feature

Comment: Could you point the junk filter location in Outlook client, i wonder do a test.